# Associate one column in table with two existing tables

Tags: sql, linq, orm, migration, database-migration

My DB has following tables:

1. `Resource`: Some resources can be uploaded on site
2. `Groups`: Groups on site
3. `Users`: Users on site (not necessarily be part of any group but could be if they like)

Now, when some one uploads a resource then currently, ownership of that resource is given to it's `uploader` by default. So `resource` table has column `OwnerID` with foreign key association to `User` table.

But now, this has to be changed such that ownership of a `resource` could be given to either a user or entire group.

I'm trying to decide the migration scheme, to move this `owner` being user to an entity that could be either `user` or `group`. Intuition is that when someone uploads a material, he can choose its owner to be a `user` or entire `group`.

Currently my migration plans involves:

1. Add `OwnerType` (User, Group, Global) and `UserOwner` and `GroupOwner` within the `Material` table (probably worse normalized table).
2. `OwnerType` could be `Global` if owner is everyone --or-- `Group` if owner is `group` entity else `user`.
3. Then when I'm querying the `Resource` table, I can check the `OwnerType` to condionally select its Owner from either `user` table or `group` table.

I do not know if this is good way. I'm using entity framework, and things are already started to look ugly as `User` and `Group` hardly have any relationaship that would require me to make generalized entity.

Can some expert guide me on this? What is generally considered good migration plan in this case? Thanks for any help or suggestions.